# How can I make sense of global subset relation in a topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the class of all functions $\iota: S \rightarrow X$ inserting a subset $S \subseteq X$ into a larger set.

The presence of the family $\mathcal{I}$ underlies the subset relation $\subseteq$ between sets. For example, $S$ is subset of $X$ if and only if there exists a morphism $\iota \in \mathcal{I}$ going from $S$ to $X$($S \xrightarrow{\iota} X$). $\mathcal{I}$ also underlies set intersection, set union.

Is there a way to define an analogous class $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ of monomorphism in another topos $\mathcal{E}$ in a way that allows us to do "set like" reasoning in $\mathcal{E}$?

I would like to define $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ in a way that gives me a sensible notion of intersection and union between two objects $X, Y \in \mathcal{E}$.

I would like a family $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ that satisfies at least the conditions below:

- every morphism in the family $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ is mono;
- if $X \in \mathcal{E}$ and $S$ is a subobject of $X$, then there exists a unique $m: M \rightarrow X$ contained in $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ and $S$. Said in other words, every subobject contain a unique morphism of $\mathcal{I}^\prime$
- $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ is closed under identity, that is, for every $X \in \mathcal{E}$, the identity morphism $X \xrightarrow{1_X} X$ is in $\mathcal{I}^\prime$;
- $\mathcal{I}^\prime$ is closed under composition, that is, if $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ and $Y \xrightarrow{g} Z$ belong to $\mathcal{I}^\prime$, then $X \xrightarrow{f;g} Z$ also belongs to $\mathcal{I}^\prime$
- let $f, g, h$ be morphisms in $\mathcal{E}$, as in the triangle below. If $g$ and $h$ belong to $\mathcal{I}^\prime$, then $X \xrightarrow{f;g} Z$ also belongs to $\mathcal{I}^\prime$.

[image]

All of those four properties are satisfied in the categories of Sets by the family $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: "Global element" already has a meaning in topos theory and it is unrelated to this. Anyway, your question is underspecified. You have not excluded uninteresting candidates like the empty family, or the family of identity morphisms. Nor have you required any naturality or canonicity, so there may be some horrific constructions using the axiom of choice. I suggest you think harder about the question you really want to ask.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanky you for kindly replying.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I can't think of a better title, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @ZhenLin: I will edit my question in order to make it more specified.

Comment: I think in your second bulletpoint you also want $m\in \mathcal{I}'$.

Comment: @Lucas Usually people talk about a "global membership predicate" or some variation on that. But this is not what you are defining either. This is more like $\subseteq$ than $\in$. Also, I think you should reconsider your 2-out-of-3 condition. It's false even for genuine set inclusion.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: thank you for point that

Comment: OK, I think you have a somewhat precise question now. Let me make one simple observation: the existence of such a class of inclusions is not invariant under equivalence of categories. After all, you can replace a category with its skeleton, and it is clear that a skeletal category that has a class of inclusions as you seek cannot have non-trivial disjoint unions. But on the other hand, I think if you have a proper class of objects in every isomorphism class (except maybe the isomorphism class of $0$), and if the category is wellpowered, then maybe you can use class choice to get something.